# Showing $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x^{3})}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{6}$

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x^{3})}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{6}$$
How to derive the above equality?

Looking for non complex analysis methods.

Comment: Do you know that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}~dx = \pi/2$?

Comment: Maybe if you bothered to look up methods for some other integrals and tried to apply it to this one , then showing what you tried and where you are stuck would be more useful for your own learning

Comment: An interesting homework ?

Comment: @Falcon Yep, it's a common result from using Leibniz's rule.

Comment: @jimjim maybe, but I'm a bit stuck here. That's why I asked for help.

Comment: @Yves, not homework per say. It was from a competition but I want to learn how to arrive at the solution.

Comment: @Penguin This is one u-substitution away from this common result.

Comment: If you know this result just take $u = x^3$ in the integral.

Comment: @Penguin What do you think you should substitute if you're trying to get the integrand in the form $\sin(u)/u$?

Comment: u=x^3? @spaceisdarkgreen?

Comment: You must mention things like it is from competition, try to do something , anything and then say why you are stuck . That is how you get better .

Comment: @jimjim I had it in my original post. Though, the one now is more concise(edited by moderators).

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's from the HMMO 2020 November Integration Bee qualifier test, as is the other integral OP posted.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\int\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x}dx=\int\frac{\sin(t^{3\alpha})}{t^\alpha}d(t^\alpha).$$

> $$\int\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x}dx=\int\frac{\sin(t^{3\alpha})}{t^\alpha}d(t^\alpha)=\alpha\int\frac{\sin(t^{3\alpha})}tdt.$$

Comment: Thank you! I will try it now.